# Pandas DataFrame datetime index doesn't survive JSON conversion and reconversion

Tags: python, json, datetime, pandas

I have the following snippet of Python code:

```
import pandas as pd

# print normal index
print data.index

# convert from df to JSON and back
data_json = data.to_json()
df = pd.read_json(data_json)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print df.index
```

for some reason running this returns in:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1950-01-03 00:00:00, ..., 2014-08-21 00:00:00]
Length: 16264, Freq: None, Timezone: None
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1966-10-31 00:00:00, ..., 2001-09-07 00:00:00]
Length: 16264, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on and how I can have the index persist through the transformations?

Comment: Can you post some example data where this fails?  On a dummy set it worked for me.  You should also note versions.

Comment: print sys.version
print pd.__version__

2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)| (default, Nov  4 2013, 15:30:26) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
0.12.0

The data is:
data = Quandl.get("YAHOO/INDEX_GSPC", trim_start="1950-01-03",
                     trim_end="2014-08-21")

Comment: fixed it by upgrading pandas to 0.14.1 and specifying date_format='iso' in the to_json() call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error here is that `to_json` saves dates with ms resolution by defaul, while `to_datetime` converts with nanosecond resolution by default.  To fix, either of these (but not both!) would work.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')
#OR
data_json = data.to_json(date_unit='ns')
```

As noted in comments, you can also just save the json with the dates in iso format.